# VBA for loop only iterating once

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm having trouble with this VBA - my for loop only iterates once, and when it increments it says that the method "Cells" in object "Worksheet" failed. It worked the first iteration though... I think my StatusUpdate function is breaking it, but when I comment it out, it fails anyway. Does anything stand out in the main sub to anyone? Happy to post more code if needed.

```
Sub CreateSlides()

Dim XLapp As New Excel.Workbook

Dim WS As New Excel.Worksheet

Set XLapp = Excel.Workbooks.Open("J:\OPERATIONS\CAPITAL PROJECTS\Clara\test.xlsx")

Set WS = XLapp.Sheets(1)

XLapp.Activate
WS.Select

Dim CD As Integer
CD = 0

Dim cell As Range

Dim i As Integer

Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Delete old slides
If ActivePresentation.Slides.Count > 1 Then
    Call DeleteSlides
End If

'Loop through each used row in Column A
For i = 2 To LastRow

    CD = WS.Cells(i, 35).Value

    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Copy
    ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste (ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1)

    ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes("project").TextFrame.TextRange = WS.Cells(i, 7).Value
    ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes("park location").TextFrame.TextRange = WS.Cells(i, 9).Value
    ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes("cb").TextFrame.TextRange = Right(WS.Cells(i, 36).Text, 2)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes("cm").TextFrame.TextRange = (CouncilMember(CD))
    ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes("scope").TextFrame.TextRange = WS.Cells(i, 8).Value
    ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes("funding").TextFrame.TextRange = FundingEst(i)
    ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes("status").TextFrame.TextRange = StatusUpdate(i)

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line does it error in your loop?

Comment: `Dim XLapp As New Excel.Workbook` stands out very much as a misnommer and an illegal `New`ing up of an object that can't be created like this, yes. How does it even compile?

Comment: `LastRow` should be a `Long`. The largest possible value for `Integer` is 32,767 - a worksheet can have many times more rows than that.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - `Dim XLapp As New Excel.Workbook` would potentially cause a *run-time* error in this case (429 - ActiveX component can't create object), not a compile error.  VBA doesn't attempt to create the default instance unless it is accessed. The `Set` statement is the first "usage", and that over-writes the reference to the uninstantiated default.  You can confirm this behavior with `Dim XLapp As New Excel.Workbook: Debug.Print XLapp.Name`.  *That* will throw.

Comment: @Comintern ok, compiles. can't possibly get anywhere near the loop though.

Comment: It runs fine too. The `New` assignment is never used.  It will only try to new up an instance if `XLapp` or `WS` are used without being `Set`. In this case, the `New` keyword is completely superfluous because they are never accessed while they are `Nothing`.

Comment: What is WS on the second iteration?

Answer (score 0):

you a re not running through column a but to the 35th column in the sheet. change

```
CD = WS.Cells(i, 35).Value
```

to

```
CD = WS.Cells(i, 1).Value
```

Also, if whatever is in those cells is not an integer, but text or something else, you will get an error?